# Apache configuration in production environment

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, configuration-management

I have an apache configuration (the test version) that is working good. When I pass to production configuration, my clients says that they have the error 400 bad request when requesting web services hosted in the server (wsdl/soap).

My question is : How can I test that the production configuration is the same that the test configuration.

Comment: Are you sure that it must be the apache config? Couldn't it be selinux etc. as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, "configuration" in your case includes not just Apache but any other application your using (PHP, MySQL, etc...), the OS and even the hardware and network configuration. Your test and production Apache configurations could be identical but if the directory permissions are wrong, or the network firewall isn't setup, or you forgot to update a hard coded IP address it either just won't work, or worse, will appear to work for a while and then break when you're not looking.

For testing purposes I wouldn't look at it from the standpoint of checking all the configuration besides perhaps a few critical parameters (installed applications, versions, any important hard-coded addresses, critical server parameters, etc...). After that I would just start hitting the web server with a variety of requests and making sure I get the expected response. I would test a variety of content types in a variety of locations. You don't want to just test loading `BigPageWithEverything.php` as if that fails you don't know exactly what the problem is (though that kind of test can be useful in addition to other tests).

I haven't used any web server test framework beyond ab/siege but mainly for benchmarking purposes, which is another good area to get some numbers with while testing.